Learning to write an HTTP 1.1 server, why does my server pause & surge with a high number of requests?
As a learning exercise, I am writing an HTTP server and trying to implement the HTTP 1.1 protocol myself.
When I run benchmarks that have a high number of concurrent requests that reuse their socket, the performance is great. However, when I send a high number of requests on many connections or when disabling keep-alive on the client, the server periodically pauses & surges as it processes the requests see video here.
I am using this command for stress testing:
# 50000 requests
# 5 connections
oha -n 50000 -c 5 --latency-correction --disable-keepalive http://localhost:8080

A more realistic scenario is "5000 users doing 5 requests each, reusing their socket". This also chokes the Rust http server.
However it runs great if there is minimal connections and lots of requests:
oha -n 50000 -c 5 --latency-correction http://localhost:8080

Without --disable-keepalive the performance is amazing, I assume that's because I am reusing sockets and the total number of requests are reduced.
One thing I wondered about was if this was caused by the async runtime. So I tried the the equivalent code using async_std (using both the local and multi threaded executors), smol, may, rayon, OS threads, and Tokio. Every case exhibits the same surging behaviour.
This also happens in the http server example provided by May
As a sanity check, I wrote a simple hello world http server in Go using their standard library and benchmarked it with the same tooling. The Go server processed requests quickly, in a consistent fashion.
This indicates that the benchmarking tool is fine and there is something wrong with my implementation.
This is the server code:
use std::io;
use bytes::BufMut;
use tokio::io::AsyncReadExt;
use tokio::io::AsyncWriteExt;
use tokio::net::TcpListener;

async fn main_async() -> io::Result<()> {
  let listener = TcpListener::bind("0.0.0.0:8080").await?;

  while let Ok((mut stream, _)) = listener.accept().await {
    tokio::task::spawn(async move {
      let mut buf = Vec::<u8>::new();

      loop {
        let mut raw_headers = [httparse::EMPTY_HEADER; 16];
        let mut raw_request = httparse::Request::new(&mut raw_headers);

        match raw_request.parse(&buf) {
          Ok(httparse::Status::Complete(_body_start)) => {
            // Send back static response for now
            stream
              .write_all(b"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: 11\r\n\r\nHello World")
              .await
              .unwrap();

            buf.clear();
          }
          Ok(httparse::Status::Partial) => {
            let mut temp_buf = vec![0; 512];
            match stream.read(&mut temp_buf).await {
              Ok(0) => break,
              Ok(n) => buf.put(&temp_buf[0..n]),
              Err(err) => println!("err = {err:?}"),
            }
            continue;
          }
          Err(_) => todo!()
        };
      }
    });
  }

  Ok(())
}

fn main() {
  let rt = tokio::runtime::Builder::new_multi_thread()
    .enable_all()
    .worker_threads(16)
    .build()
    .unwrap();

  rt.block_on(main_async()).unwrap();
}

Is this a result of some internal buffer limit within the standard library TcpListener or am I just missing something simple?

TcpListener and related types are a fairly thin layer over BSD sockets, so this may be a Linux question more than a Rust one, especially given that it behaves the same across runtimes. It might be illuminating to strace -f your server to better understand what's going on.

Does the Go http server implementation use BSD sockets? I was considering experimenting with a userland socket implementation like smoltcp https://github.com/ANLAB-KAIST/usnet_sockets however it's unmaintained and I need to figure out how to get it working.

I haven't checked, but I expect Go uses them as well, as they're how you do networking on Unix-like systems, and even on Windows. But it might be using them in a different way, e.g. by automatically disabling NAGLE or enabling SO_REUSEADDR. The intended accent was on "thin layer", meaning I'd expect the same behavior if you wrote your server in C using equivalent code.

"The Go server processed requests quickly, in a consistent fashion."  - and also with the same average throughput as your code? Or significantly faster/slower?

@SteffenUllrich I created a repo with my experiments and results. Here you can see the results compared to Go and Nodejs: https://alshdavid.github.io/rust-http-benchmarks/_reports/saved/r-1000_c-50000_keepalive-false.html
The sources are available here: https://github.com/alshdavid/rust-http-benchmarks
